# Java Play akka module creation

Tags: java, playframework, akka

I am working on java play akka and I need to create new play and akka module. Please let me know how to create a new play and akka module individually.

Answer (score 0):

> You need to have JAVA SDK & SBT installed on your system.

And then You can create a new Java / Scala Play Project

```
sbt new playframework/play-java-seed.g8
```

Source: [java Play Documentation](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/NewApplication)

Java Play comes bundled with Akka so no need to have it installed manually.

> You can edit your Akka Threads / Configuration from application.conf

Then further you can use Akka Actors for creating Akka Actors and then inject the Actor in the Controller.

Reference: [Java Akka Actor System](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/JavaAkka)